# ¿como dar permiso de AUTO-INICIO en API 23 o superior?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando en una aplicacion de alarma y funciona perfecto en segundo plano, pero cuando reinicio el movil el servicio no inicia, debo dar el **permisio de auto inicio** como lo tienen las aplicacion de **Whatsapp y messenger** pero como lo hago.

Aqui esta la opcion de auto inicio o en otros dispositivos proteccion contra bateria

[image]

Comment: Qué has hecho hasta ahora? Dónde te ha fallado? Hace falta ver lo que has intentado para ver si tienes un error y poder ayudarte, o al menos poder ver lo que has intentado. Mira [ask] y [tour] para poder editar la pregunta y que quede una "buena" pregunta.

Comment: Es importante agregar lo que has investigado o tratado.